Python script to run in nifi application for routing flowfiles based on the flowfile content atrribute if lastclock is greaterthan nowminus1minute
{
"Lastclock": epochformat,
"Lastvalue": 98.5778
}
I want to routeflowfiles based on lastclock values if it is greaterthan now-1min then route to success remaining to failure

You could just pull the timestamp millis out of the JSON and into a FlowFile attribute and then use RouteOnAttribute much like described in ROuting entire Json Contents based on json field.
